# xaml parse exception occurs in Visual studio on deserialization of xml to create object

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I am working on **`c#  using silverlight-5 in VS2012`** and trying to derialize.

My code to do this is as follows :

```
Filename is `attribute.cs`
    using System;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Documents;
    using System.Windows.Ink;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
    using System.Windows.Shapes;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
    using System.Runtime;
    using System.Xml.Serialization;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Diagnostics;



    namespace Model.XML
    {
        [DataContract]
        public class attribute
        {
            [DataMember]
            public string type { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public string displayed { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public string add_remove { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public string ccypair { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public List<int> item { get; set; }

            public static void Main()
            {
               // System.IO.StreamReader myFileStream = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\Users\\SHEK\\Desktop\\VannakNew\\DEV_CENTER\\Model\\XML\\XmlParameter.xml");
                FileStream myFileStream = new FileStream(@"\XmlParameter.xml", FileMode.Open); //On debugging after this line the code breaks and generate exception
                attribute mainobj = null;
                XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(attribute));
                mainobj = ser.Deserialize(myFileStream) as attribute;
                Debug.WriteLine(mainobj.type);  
            }        
        }
    }
```

[image]
Just after the line `FileStream myFileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\SHEK\Desktop\VannakNew\DEV_CENTER\DEV_CENTER\Parameters.xaml", FileMode.Open);` it switches to the MainPage.Xaml.cs and there it shows this exception .

Why it do so ?
**What i hav to do is :**
I have an xml file and there is a class called `attricute.cs` in xml file i have to display it's node elements.
The xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<parameter>
  <name>bands_amounts</name>
  <label>Bands Amounts</label>
  <unit></unit>
  <component>
    <type>List</type>
    <attributes>
      <type>Integer</type>
      <displayed>4</displayed>
      <add_remove>yes</add_remove>
      <item>1 000 000</item>
      <item>5 000 000</item>
      <item>10 000 000</item>
      <item>20 000 000</item>
    </attributes>
    <attributes>
      <ccypair>XAUUSD</ccypair>
      <item>100</item>
      <item>500</item>
      <item>1000</item>
    </attributes>
  </component >
</parameter>
```

EDIT AFTER COMMENTS: I changed my code to this after reading the comments but the problem is it even dont executes any line  after `FileStream myFileStream = new FileStream(@"\XmlParameter.xml", FileMode.Open);` it directly show that exception again.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Runtime;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;



namespace Model.XML
{
   [XmlRoot("parameter")]

    public class attribute
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string type { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string displayed { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string add_remove { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string ccypair { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public List<int> item { get; set; }

        public static void Main()
        {
           // System.IO.StreamReader myFileStream = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\Users\\SHEK\\Desktop\\VannakNew\\DEV_CENTER\\Model\\XML\\XmlParameter.xml");
            FileStream myFileStream = new FileStream(@"\XmlParameter.xml", FileMode.Open);

            attribute mainobj = null;
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(parameter));
            mainobj = ser.Deserialize(myFileStream) as attribute;
            Debug.WriteLine(mainobj.type);  
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW; `XmlSerializer` does not use `DataMember` attributes.

Comment: [I give out -1s like hot cakes to people who insist on showing us pictures of exception helper dialogs.  Learn how to use them correctly.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JNABr.png)

Comment: I am using silverlight . It dont support "[Serialize]"

Comment: @user234839 that's fine, `XmlSerializer` doesn't use `[Serializable]` either; I didn't mention `[Serialize]` or `[Serializable]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type that you pass to `XmlSerializer` as the root type represents the root of the xml. You are passing `typeof(attribute)`. This type does not match the xml; you should be passing `typeof(Parameter)` i.e. a type that looks like the xml. For example:

```
[XmlRoot("parameter")]
public class Parameter {
    [XmlElement("component")]
    public Component Component {get;set;}
}
```

(edit, see comments) another file

```
public class Component {
    [XmlElement("attributes")]
    public List<Attribute> Attributes {get;set;}
}
```

with:

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Parameter));
var mainobj = (Parameter)ser.Deserialize(myFileStream);
```

Comment: But i want to have different files for each class like seperate class for component, seperate for  attribute and parameter. All classes must not be in same file

Comment: @user234839 do you mean the C# files? then you create multiple files and you put the class or classes that you want in each file. That is purely organisational, and does not change the answer in the slightest.

Comment: yES ;;i MEAN attribute.cs, component.cs and parameter.cs all seperately. and i am using silverlight-5 for this.

Comment: @user234839 so... just do that? See the edit. The code doesn't need to be in one file - showing them next to each-other was purely for convenience (actually, I didn't even mention files)

Comment: you mean.  your first code is in parameter.cs class and second code is in component.cs class. Could you please edit and mention the class name as well. Like there would be 3 classes here parameter, component and attribute. and how and where i will call deseralze function ? if i a=have to print "Integer" of "<type>Integer</type>" which is inside attribute.

Comment: @user234839 no, I'm sure you can simply *imagine* different classes going into different files; there is no need for me to add filenames, because **files do not matter** to the compiler. I have shown **how** to call the deserialize method; *where* you should call it is entirely up to your code, but I'm going to say "at the point where you want to deserialize". I cannot parse the last question about "a=have to print".

Comment: I have again edited the code and changed my code to follow you. But the problem is it even dont execute any line after "FileStream myFileStream = new FileStream(@"\XmlParameter.xml", FileMode.Open);" it directly again gives same exception. (it even dont access the second line which is "attribute mainobj = null;")

Comment: @user234839 if it doesn't get past the line that opens the file, then the problem is not deserialization. You will need to find out why the file isn't opening (does it exist? is it locked?). I cannot magically tell you.

Comment: i am not able to understand your code. Where are you writing these lines "XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Parameter));
var mainobj = (Parameter)ser.Deserialize(myFileStream);" .IS IT INSIDE  attribute.cs class file?c Is this Object "mainobj" belongs to the object of attribute class ?

Comment: @user234839 it **does not matter** where that code is; that goes where-ever you need to do the deserialization. I cannot tell you where you want to do deserialization: that is up to you. But specifically, it is "wherever it is in your example" - just with two lines changed.

Comment: I am sorry you even double confused me.This exception keeps on persisting. What i asked is very simple:(a) suppose i have any xml content stored in a string(lets say "xmlstring").(b) I have 3 different files parameter.cs, componenet.cs and attribute.cs which contain s their respective name class. I am working inside attrbute class which is in attribute.cs NOW QUESTION COMES TO MIND IS (1) When and where i have to put the data inside these square brackets [WhatShouldBeWrittenInsideThem] for each class.

Comment: My code inside the attribute class main function is: "public static void Main()
        {          
            string xmlstring = @"<contains my xml contents>";
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(parameter));
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlstring));
            attribute Object1 = (attribute)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            Debug.WriteLine(Object1.type);
        }
"

Comment: @user234839 the code I have posted in my answer, along with the class in the question (I edited `attribute` to `Attribute`, but that's all) works successfully to deserialize the xml shown in the question.

Comment: `attribute Object1 = (attribute)serializer.Deserialize(...)` - why? It is deserializing a `Parameter`, not an `attribute`? If that succeeds in deserializing, it will fail with a type cast exception. You will notice that I cast to `Parameter` in the code shown in the answer.

Comment: I have doubt in your explanation. If you see my xml code there is a list of <item> which i handle in c# code liek this  public List<attributes> attribut { get; set; } but when i do "Debug.WriteLine(attrib.item);" where it is inside "var Object1 = (parameter)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
            foreach (var attrib in Object1.component.attribut)" THEN ON DEBUGGING IT DONT SHOW "1 000 000" and "5 000 000" etc. How to see thse values because i have to use them in my code.

Comment: i still have problem with it. could you please see my this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429534/how-to-deserialize-the-xmlelement-containing-list-in-xml  Thanks a lot.